# Best way to represent icons on a background image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, dictionary, bitmap

I have a map image (bitmap, ~4MB) that contains services (i.e. restrooms/elevators/exits/etc..) Based on user selection from a table I would like to show the map with the selected service only. For example, if the user selects restrooms the map appears with only restrooms colored/highlighted. I have the separate icons for the services. There are a few ways to do this:

a) Create static map images of each service (one with restrooms highlighted, one with elevators highlighted, etc..) However that will use a lot of memory since I will store ~8 images one for each service (8*4MB)

b) Have one map image but dynamically draw the highlighted/selected icons over the map using coordinates. Very tedious, time consuming, and annoying.

Are there any other ways to go about this? Is there a way to reduce bmp file image size without obliterating the quality?

Thanks

Edit: Went with the static images choice a above. Converted bmp to png (went down from 4MB to 150KB).

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I would've thought that the first option would be "Very tedious, time consuming, and annoying."

Suppose you find out that another bathroom has been added. I'd much prefer to put in an X coordinate and a y coordinate and be done with it.

I'd create an array of x and y coordinates and use a for loop to add the bathrooms.
Shove the icons in imageViews and be done with it.

```
// Mock code
for (Bathroom *bathroom in bathroomArray) {
    UIImageView *bathroomImgView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    bathroomImgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BathroomIcon.png"];
    bathroomImgView.center = CGPointMake(bathroom.x, bathroom.y);
    [mapHolder addObject:bathroomImgView];
}
```

The above code assumes that you have a UIView surrounding the bitmap of the map, and a bunch of custom objects that each have an x and y value in an array called bathroomArray.

Comment: Thanks XenEl, however, how do I figure out the coordinates on the image? My image is 1700x1700 however if I add the icon at position (300,300) it does not appear at that exact position in the UIImageView/iphone. I declare the imageview as:

    self.mapim.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    self.mapim.contentMode = (UIViewContentModeScaleToFill);

Comment: See here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html, states: You should avoid creating UIImage objects that are greater than 1024 x 1024 in size.

Comment: I think there must be a better way to do what you're trying to do, possibly with the google maps api or a smaller image with zoom. Or maybe multiple smaller images loaded individually in a grid.

Comment: i don't think that's the issue though.. I think it is a matter of scaling things. Scale to fill probably resizes it to a lower res.

Comment: It would, assuming the image view isn't as large as you image. If you're going to be using the same 1700 x 1700 image, you can manually set the size of the image view to that.